# Problems with EF6-DatabaseContext and DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datatemplate, dbcontext

!!The Post is updated, please see below!!

So, after 6hours I need help again.

Situation:
- A given EF6 Database context. (working)
- Using a MVVM approach

Important parts form the database context:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
      public DbSet<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Serie> Series { get; set; }
    }
```

Important part from Serie.cs

```
public class Serie
{
    public Int64 SerieId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(15)]
    public String SerieNr { get; set; }
    public virtual Operation CurrentOperation { get; set; }
}
```

Important part from Operation.cs

```
public class Operation
{

    public Operation()
    {
        this.Series = new ObservableCollection<Serie>();
    }

    public int OperationId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Serie> Series { get; set; }

}
```

Now there is a WPF-Page "BestandPage.xaml":

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Operations}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name }" />
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Series}"></ListView>
                 </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Its ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Operation> Operations { get { return this._Operations; } set { } }
    private ObservableCollection<Operation> _Operations = new ObservableCollection<Operation>();
    public BestandPageViewModel()
    {

        using (var _context = new ProdPlanNET.Models.DatabaseContext())
        {
            _context.Operations.Load();
            var a = _context.Operations.Local;

            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Operations");

        }

    }
```

I would like a view like

```
Operation1   Operation2   Operation3  (Label)
------------------------------------
Serie1.1     Serie2.1     Serie3.1    (ListView, containing the series of each operation)
Serie1.2     Serie3.1     Serie3.2
```

It doesn't work.
I see the Operation names, but I don't know how to display the according series.
I am not sure is the problem the binding or the ViewModel.

!!!!!UPDATE!!!!!

I changed my ViewModel like this:

```
class BestandPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    public ObservableCollection<ViewObject> ViewObjects { get { return this._ViewObjects; } set { } }

    private ObservableCollection<ViewObject> _ViewObjects = new ObservableCollection<ViewObject>();

    public BestandPageViewModel()
    {

        using (var _context = new ProdPlanNET.Models.DatabaseContext())
        {

            foreach ( Operation ops in _context.Operations ){
                _ViewObjects.Add(new ViewObject() { Name = ops.Name, Amount=ops.Series.Count.ToString(), Series = ops.Series.Select(s=>s.SerieNr) });
            }
            MessageBox.Show(this._ViewObjects.Count.ToString());

            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Operations");

        }

    }

    public class ViewObject
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Amount { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<String> Series { get; set; }
        public ViewObject()
        {
            this.Series = new ObservableCollection<String>();
        }

    }

}
```

I create "ViewObjects". Is that a "nice" solution?

Now the Problem is just the DataTemplate, I would like as already mentioned a view like

```
Operation1   Operation2   Operation3  (Label)
------------------------------------
Serie1.1     Serie2.1     Serie3.1    (ListView, containing the series of each operation)
Serie1.2     Serie3.1     Serie3.2
```

at the time it looks like:

```
Operation1
---------
Serie1.1
Serie1.2
Serie1.3

Operation2
---------
Serie2.1
Serie2.2
Serie2.1
```

XAML Code:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewObjects}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name }" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding Amount }" />
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Series}"></ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewObjects}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name }" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding Amount }" />
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Series}"></ListView>
                    </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

I think I am not a friend with WPF. Good night.